# How to implement both DrawerNavigator and StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am developing an app using react-native-navigation and I want to have a StackNavigator and a DrawerNavigator in the project. So, I have implemented them in the app.js but the apps crashes giving this error "The development server returned response error with code: 500".I have implemented them separetly and it works but I couldn't implement them together.Any suggestion?

this is my code for app.js

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';

import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import {
    createStackNavigator,
    DrawerNavigator,
    DrawerItems
} from "react-navigation";

import {
    Container,
    Header,
    Content,
    Thumbnail,
    Button,
    Body
} from 'native-base';

import Profile from './components/Profile.js';
import Main from './components/Main.js';
import Login from './components/Login.js';
import Product from './components/Product.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
           <Navapp />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    // styles here
});

export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: Main
    },
    Profile: {
        screen: Profile
    },
}, {
initialRouteName: 'Main',
contentComponent: CustomDrawer,
drawerPosition: 'Left',
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
});

export const CustomDrawer = (props) => ( 
    <Container>
        <Header style = {
            styles.headerStyle
        }>
            <Body style = {
                styles.bodyStyle
            }>
                <Thumbnail style = {
                    {
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100
                    }
                }
                source = {
                    require('../image/logo.png')
                }/> 
            </Body> 
        </Header>
        <Content>
            <DrawerItems { ...props}  /> 
        </Content > 
    </Container>
)

export const Navapp = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    Drawer: {
        screen: Drawer
    },
    Product: {
        screen: Product
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about what do you want, like app UI?

Comment: I want the first page to be a login page then after submitting the login data he gets redirected to the main page that has a DrawerNavigator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a very similar setup for my app, this is how I went about handling it. First I created a stack navigator with the routes that I wanted logged in users to see, and I place that navigator inside a drawer navigator (you can put more than one in there if you want). Finally I created my top-level navigator, whose initial route points to the login page; upon logging in I navigate the user to the second route, which points to my drawer navigator.

In practice it looks like this:

```
// Main Screens for Drawer Navigator
export const MainStack = StackNavigator({
  Dashboard: {
    screen: Dashboard,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Dashboard',
      gesturesEnabled: false,
      headerLeft: null
    }
  },

  Notifications: {
    screen: Notifications,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Notifications'
    }
  }
}, { headerMode: 'screen' } );

// Drawer Navigator
export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  MainStack: {
    screen: MainStack
  }
});


// Main App Navigation
export const AppStack = StackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  },

  Drawer: {
    screen: Drawer,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }
  }
}, { headerMode: 'none' } );

// In Your App.js
<AppStack />
```

Note that in the last stack navigator, the drawer screen has header set to null; this is because with nested stack navigators you can sometimes run into an issue where you'll have duplicate headers. This will hide the top-level navigator's header and let you show / customize the headers for your nested navigators.

Comment: How to pass data from "Login" to "Dashboard" component?

Comment: @kalyan711987 That depends on what you mean by passing data. If you want to navigate from the login screen to the dashboard screen and pass props to the dashboard component at the same time, you could do something like:
`this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard', { foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' });`
Then, in your Dashboard component you could access `foo` and `bar` within:
`this.props.navigation.state.params`

Comment: @MattyCodes its giving me error.
`Error: The component for route 'Main' must be a React component.`. I'm stuck since two days.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the way we can implement both Stack and Drawer Navigation has been made much simpler. Here you guys can refer to my code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import MenuComponent from "../MenuComponent";
import DishDetailComponent from "../DishDetailComponent";
import HomeComponent from "../HomeComponent";

/**
 * @author BadalSherpa
 * @function HomeNavigation
 **/

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const HomeNavigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeComponent} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Menu' component={MenuComponent} />
      <Stack.Screen name='Dish-Detail' component={DishDetailComponent} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MenuNavigation = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
      <Stack.Screen name='Menu' component={MenuComponent} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const DrawerNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name='Home' component={HomeNavigation} />  //Here is where we are combining Stack Navigator to Drawer Navigator
      <Drawer.Screen name='Menu' component={MenuNavigation} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default DrawerNavigation;
```

Then you can simple return this inside NavigationContainer which will have both Stack and Drawer Navigator working together.

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <HomeNavigation />
 </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: This does not work, to make it work; since you're exporting `<DrawerNavigation />`, wrap it inside `<NavigationContainer>`

Comment: Also, if this following code helped me even better: 

`<NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <SideBar {...props} />}>
          <Drawer.Screen name='App' component={App} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>`

Comment: Yes shivam jha I am wrapping drawer navigation inside the NavigationContainer. Since I am importing the DrawerNavigation as default so I am importing it as HomeNavigation in my MainComponent. ```<NavigationContainer>
      <HomeNavigation />
 </NavigationContainer>``` <HomeNavigation/> here is the Content of DrawerNavigation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I use them

```
const HomeStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'screen',
  },
);

const MainDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStackNavigator,
    },
  },
  {
    drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
    drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
    drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
    contentComponent: SlideMenu,
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
    },
  },
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the Login screen have the Drawer. How to disable that?

Comment: I want the drawer to be only on the Main screen

Comment: @tuledev its giving me error.
`Error: The component for route 'Main' must be a React component.`. I'm stuck since two days.

Answer (score 0):

same issue with me, Then i just change my emulator and update the version and it worked 100%.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different take where the drawer navigator controls a stack navigator.  Each selection in the drawer will push a child stack element so there is a one-to-one match between the drawer and stack.  This is more typical behavior in my experience.  All but the home have a title with back navigation indicator.

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {
  CompositeNavigationProp,
  NavigationContainer,
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  StackNavigationProp,
} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './SettingsScreen';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentComponentProps,
  DrawerContentOptions,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItem,
  DrawerNavigationProp,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

type NoProps = Record<string, object>;
export type ScreenNavigationProps = CompositeNavigationProp<
  StackNavigationProp<NoProps>,
  DrawerNavigationProp<NoProps>
>;

export type DrawerProps = DrawerContentComponentProps<DrawerContentOptions>;
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator(); // https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

/**
 * Render the content of the drawer.  When an item is selected
 * it closes the drawer and pushes an element on the stack nav.
 * @param props
 */
function CustomDrawerContent(props: DrawerProps) {
  const navigation = (props.navigation as unknown) as ScreenNavigationProps;

  const openScreen = (name: string) => () => {
    navigation.navigate('Home', {screen: name});
    navigation.closeDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      {/* <DrawerItemList {...props} /> */}
      <DrawerItem label="Home" onPress={openScreen('Home')} />
      <DrawerItem label="Settings" onPress={openScreen('Settings')} />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

/**
 * Render the Home Stack Navigator.
 */
function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

/**
 * Render the Home Drawer with a custom drawerContent.
 */
function HomeDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.app}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <HomeDrawer />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {flex: 1},
});

export default App;
```

The HomeScreen can provide a menu to open the drawer:

```
  const navigation = useNavigation<ScreenNavigationProps>();

  const openDrawer = () => {
    navigation.openDrawer();
  };
```